# What happens if you Move Earth from under a big tall stone building?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

Our party is currently looking for a way of destroying or heavily damaging a castle-like mansion. It is a tall stone building, roughly 45x45 meters. While researching the ways of doing it, our druid recalled that he can [Move Earth](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/moveEarth.htm) from under a castle. A [5th edition version](https://www.dnd-spells.com/spell/move-earth) of the spell is more thorough and mentions that you can lower the earth's elevation and that

> If the way you shape the terrain would make a structure unstable, it might collapse.

However, it seems that 3.5 version of the spell can only move 10ft.-deep chunks of earth.
Will 3 casts of the Move Earth spell (e.g. 30ft. of earth gradually removed from under the half of the building) be enough to heavily damage or topple it? Or will our druid just create a Pisa-like landmark for the people living nearby?

Comment: Note: the spell can cover a 750 x 750 ft. square, which is roughly 250 x 250 m. square, so the area under the mansion will not be an issue.

Comment: Note that buildings have foundations.  The foundation might be more than 10 feet deep on a "tall stone building".  In fact, they may have dug down to bedrock (in some areas, bedrock isn't far down).  Deep foundations (below the frost line) are required to make buildings that don't get bent out of shape every winter by ice "lifting" parts of them.  So, what is the climate, how close is bedrock, and how stable is the structure?

Comment: @Yakk As of now we don't know all the info, we are looking into all possibilities. The climate is continental, we don't think there is bedrock. The structure is "П"-like, there might be some underground parts as well, so we don't know how deep the foundation is.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### 1 cast of Move Earth will accomplish what you need. 3 casts of Move Earth will completely obliterate enemy defences

It used to be a common siege tactic to dig a tunnel (which with the battlefield engineering available at the time would be less than 10 ft.) under the enemy wall or tower, secure the ceiling with wooden supports... and light them on fire. The aim was to dig the tunnel under a load-bearing fragment of the structure, such as a corner. Removing earth veeery slowly would possibly leave the part of the structure directly above intact, but the *connection* between it and the rest of the building, the part sitting on the edge of your earthworks would be reduced to rubble.

FYI, enjoy an image presenting a brick building which suffered from earth settling due to mining activity. The ground settling happened over years and the height difference was less than a foot in height. 
[image: Bytom's ruined building]

### Imagine what 10 ft. of difference would do to that wall.

Walls are made of crumbly materials and don't stretch well at all. Stretching a wall 10ft. downwards will definitely make it crumble in the seams.

Comment: A very vivid example :D Let's just hope it is not a dwarven-built earthquake-moveearth-proof mansion

Comment: You should have a look at Staufen 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Staufen_im_Breisgau#Geothermal_drilling_controversy in Germany, where one can observe that very graphically currently (up to 1 meter wide rips through walls, historic and modern).

Comment: @AngeloFuchs I come from an area with extensive mining damage. While I have not experienced the problem of my house being ripped apart by settling ground I have seen some with lots of damage. For the OP, however, it would be quite worthwhile.

Answer (score 8):

You probably need to refer to **Stronghold Builder's Guidebook**.

It lists spells that can potentially damage a structure.

They are Disintegrate, Earthquake, Soften Earth and Stone, Stone Shape, Transmute Rock to Mud, Warp Wood, Wood Shape (pp. 99-100)

The Move Earth spell is not in the list. Moreover, in the Sapping section of this book (p. 100) it reads:

> Note that Move Earth is not helpful here, since it cannot be used for tunneling and doesn't affect structures.

Anyway you handle it, this book is your best friend for ajudicating structures. It has all the statistics for hardness and hitpoints of walls of different material and thickness, recomendations for spells for both defending and attacking structures. It describes other nonmagical means of attacking structures.

Even **if you rule that Move Earth can be used**, you can refer to the **Sapping rules** (p. 100) to figure out the effect.

> If you can dig underneath a wall, you can collapse it by removing its foundation. In general it takes an hour of digging to weaken a section of wall to the point where it takes 2d6x10 points of damage.

(10x10 feet section mentioned)

Comment: +1 for the book, but I am not sure I agree with its conclusion about Move Earth.

Comment: @Matthieu M. Even if you do rule that Move Earth is useful, the book has rules for Sapping that can help to figure out the effect of the spell.

Comment: Yes, that and the hardness/hit points of walls, etc... is very useful because it's a bit hard to come up with on the fly!

Answer (score 3):

On historical method of destroying castle walls was called "mining" or "sapping".  This involved digging a tunnel under the wall, then burning out the wood shoring to collapse the tunnel.  The weight of the wall above the collapsed tunnel would bring down a section of wall with far less drop and area than your druid's spell can produce -- the tunnels were typically only a few feet high and wide.

It doesn't take much loss of support to undermine (a word that stems directly from this technique) a dry stone wall.  Mortared walls are a little sturdier, but removing ten feet of height will (real world) *at the very least* fracture the wall at each point where it crosses the scarp created by the spell.  It's almost certain that a castle wall will collapse at that point, though it may remain standing beyond the nearest corner or reinforcing tower.

Comment: Great minds think alike :)

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: I am not an architect*

First of all, the spell *Move Earth* can only affect *dirt (clay, loam, sand)*, so if the mansion is built on a bedrock, then it is not possible to dig underneath.

Beyond that, I would point out that creating tunnels under walls to collapse them is a tried and proven strategy which was used notably in the Middle Age when attempting to storm castles. Storming the breach would still be required, but the partly collapsed wall was easier to scale.

This is called [Mining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mining_%28military%29), and it can be supplemented by detonating an explosive charge under the wall.

Comment: Beat me by two minutes.  You posted while I was typing...

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the Mining technique, looks like fun indeed! However, this involves digging a tunnel (empty space) and collapsing it instantly, while Move Earth seems to be removing the earth smoothly. Do you think that makes any difference on the collapsing effect?

Comment: @Vilmar: Unclear, to be honest. The "instant" collapse seems more like a practical matter: the tunnel has to be sustained while it is dug because digging takes time, and the collapsing is "instant" because it is done in the simplest way available (do you want to send people in to collapse it?). I think that a drop of 10 ft. would still be damaging.